# Is it safe to use web3 with electron/angular?

Tags: web3js, private-key, keystore

I am building an electron or angular (not sure yet) application integrated with web3. I will be using a parity node and infura as a fallback node to communicate with the blockchain. I will be generating/importing keystore files. With keythereum and electron I can load these files and extract the private key with a password to sign transactions that I can send to the nodes.

The private key is exposed while signing the transaction. Is there a security issue?